# Why is Colossus so hell bent on recruiting Deadpool?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

### A part of the X-Men?

Throughout the movie we see that Colossus is continually harping on Deadpool to become a part of the X-Men.

> **Deadpool:** [to Colossus]Listen! If I ever decide to become a crime-fighting shit swizzler, who rooms with a bunch of other little
>   whiners at Neverland Mansion with some creepy, old, bald, Heaven's
>   Gate-looking motherfucker... on that day, I'll send your shiny, happy
>   ass a friend request!

From what we see, Deadpool is not really the embodiment of the X-Men, as he commits murder regularly, even if the people he kills are bad guys.

So what is the motivation for Colossus and I guess Professor Xavier to have Deadpool as an X-Men?

Preferable in-universe answers only, but out-of-universe answers are fine if necessary.

Comment: My best bet would be to get this maniac under control somehow =)
Especially when you consider the dispute between humans and mutants, pictured in all X-Men films. Deadpool is not really a good example for mutants getting along fine with humans. They know they can't take him by force, so they try it with friendship

Comment: Well, much like your Uncle Luke trying to teach you how to use the light side of the Force, they want to teach Deadpool how to be a good guy and use his powers for good, without all the killing.Though, the difference between you and him, is that he already uses his powers for good. Just in an evil way.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, fat chance, My grandfather is god to me.

Comment: @KyloRen: And in the end, your grandfather realized his mistakes, redeemed himself, and died as a good guy.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks don't let one little misstep redefine a guy's entire life....

Comment: @Hellion: Exactly! Just cause he killed his own father doesn't make Kylo unredeemable. :D

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, Lalalalalalalalalalalalalalala, Not listening.

Comment: Like how religious people keep wanting you to join them or anyone who thinks they have something good to share and they just have to share no matter what

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Professor X’s objectives are the following:

- Educate and train mutants to be safe using their powers.
- Help them to feel comfortable with the fact they are mutants and the world hates them.
- Protect them from the outside world, and the outside world from them.

When a student with higher potential appears, they are invited to join the ranks of the X-Men or New Mutants.

Deadpool is a walking danger, but Xavier can read his mind and know that, in the very bottom of his soul, he's not a villain.

So, as he's a mutant, he could be a perfect addition to the Professor’s team, if he's *polished* enough.

Xavier had previous experience training and educating fierce assasins (Wolverine) and "people with attitude problems" (Gambit, Havoc,...) so he hasn't a reason to think why he won't be able to *tame* Wade.

Comment: “if he's *polished* enough” — Colossus could also look fabulous if they polished him a bit more.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the reasoning for each character is different.

For Colossus:

- In this film (and throughout the comics) Colossus is the kind of character who believes in the innate goodness of people. *But* he is also tormented by his own past: [image]

I think that this makes him the kind of hero who wants to save people, not just from outward forces, but themselves, Deadpool is totally into self harm. But Colossus is also about redemption, and Wade might be his favorite pet project.

When it comes to Xavier, however, that's more about control.

- Let's be honest, there are a lot of fan-theories out there about how Xavier likes to control people. We've heard how he could have been contriving relationships and screwing up brains in order to subtly manipulate everything, especially those people who are too powerful for their own good.

[image: Like So]

I think that both characters want Deadpool to be part of their dream team, but for different reasons.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange! Congratulations on a good post (not really first, but close enough). It has a comic reference, and backup (whether quotes, comic, or pictures) is definitely a plus around here.

Comment: That is absolutely awesome to hear. (insert superfluous emojis here)

Answer (score 1):

My best answer would be that he thinks Deadpool could be a big asset to the X-Men.

DP has shown to be an excellent combatant, and with some top tier training from Prof. X, he would help them out immensely.

Also as was previously pointed out in the comments, keeping that maniac under control would be helpful too.